# Include file does not work

Tags: nginx, ssi

I'm trying to include a page with SSI.

```
<!--#include file="test1.shtml"-->
```

But it doesn't work, I don't know why. SSI is activated on nginx.

```
ssi on;
```

The test1.shtml file exists, and has the good right. I have alos tested that :

```
<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
<!--# set var="test" value="Hello nginx!" -->
<!--# echo var="test" -->
```

And it works good, so SSI is really activated.
Anyone can help me ?

BR

Eric

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of the `file` part of `<!--#include file="test1.shtml"-->`.

Maybe try `<!--#include virtual="test1.shtml" -->`??

Let me know if it works!